# What should we do about excessive minor edits?

Tags: discussion, closing

Of late I have noticed quite a few minor edits being carried out by this "[Ben](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/73976/ben)" fellow. I'm not particularly sure if he's serious about his grammar or if he's just trying to make himself known by editing everyone's posts just so he can [get his face on everything](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/73976/ben?tab=activity&sort=revisions)...

Is it a particularly bad thing to go around on a "serial-editing" spree? Should this madman be stopped?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to fix broken windows

Comment: Is this meant to be a joke? If not, then there should be no issue when editing other people's post as long as they are useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule, the only bad thing that happens when you edit a post is that the post becomes the newest post.  If someone edits fifty posts in a row, then it obscures the actual new questions and answers from getting the reviews they deserve.

So, edit new posts aggressively.  They are already on the front page, and a good fix now may save them from a later edit when it would be less appropriate.  Don't be scared to edit older posts but try to avoid doing a bunch of them at once.  You can always save some edits to do tomorrow.

I kind of think that you knew all this, but I figured that I'd set out my understanding of the community consensus for people to opine.